# Fetch { "id,name,email" } using Facebook android sdk 4.0.x

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm working on android app using Facebook login. My app logs in successfully but i'm unable to fetch "id,name,email" of logged in user. Application crashes on executing Graphrequest

Here is my code of callbackmanager

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
              //  Toast.makeText(c, "LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
               String userID= token.getUserId();
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code

                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName)).setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

         }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(c, "LOGGED IN CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(c, "LOG IN ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any error message/reports from the point where it crashes?

Comment: Nops. not any special. it crashes with a message "Unfortunately! myApp stopped working"

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Or can you log right until when the crash happens?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without the error trace, but you could try to set the permissions in the login button object like this:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email,public_profile");
```

as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3)

and then retrieving each field inside the GraphRequest using the JsonObject

```
object.optString("id")
object.optString("name")
object.optString("email")
```